# Visual studio team services online - running a sql script

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, powershell, build, azure-devops

I have a build that I've setup using visual studio team services online. I want to execute a sql script on a remote server as a step, but don't see anything available out of box. The remote server has the agent installed on it. What's the best practice for doing this? Just put in a step that runs a powershell/bat file on the server and have that file execute the sql script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a step to run a PowerShell/batch script to execute the SQL script, and you can also create a custom build task and upload it to VSTS using TFX-CLI. For the custom task, refer to this link for details: http://shiningdragonsoftware.net/2015/08/13/tfs-build-2015-vnext-custom-tasks/

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks Eddie!

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there is [a Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ggarbuglia.runsqlserverscripts-task) available in the VSTS marketplace. As far as I can tell it's the powershell solution as mentioned in another answer, but then nicely wrapped up in a package.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17188008)

Comment: It's a package download... not a how-to. The essential part of the answer *is* the link.

Comment: And what happens if something changes and the package is either no longer available or the link breaks? You should explain basically what the package does and why that's the solution so that in future your answer is still useful to visitors.

Comment: If the package is retracted from the web, the entire answer becomes obsolete anyway.